# Paperclip does not allow jpg upload, even though it is sepcified in content type.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip to accept image uploads. I have the following validation on my attachment:

```
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpg', 'image/png'] }, size: { in: 0..500.kilobytes }
```

Uploading a png works fine, but uploading a jpeg does not work, and results in a save error which is displayed in the form. The error is on image_content_type. How can I debug this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [correct MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) to use is `image/jpeg`:

```
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'] }, size: { in: 0..500.kilobytes }
```